# how to replace new amazon S3 bucket details over old in already configured application

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, model-view-controller, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2

I have a built-in application in that he used s3 bucket now I have to create my new bucket and trying to configure the application unable to identify the issue how can I check where the issue is coming.?

With the old credentials data is uploading/receiving fine. but with the new one, it is not working

These are changes what I made in an application:

**awsConfig.php**

```
return array(
    'includes' => array('_aws'),
    'services' => array(
        'default_settings' => array(
            'params' => array(
                'key'    => 'AKIA***',              //replaced old with my new
                'secret' => '9VB4q0********',       //replaced old with my new
            )
        )
    )
);
```

I see that application is triggering **awsController.php** at first but there is no  method present in the index action

```
  public function indexAction()
    {
     //is there any to check from here where the issue is coming.?
    }
```

In the same page, i have many functions shown in this image:

[image]

and the bucket name present in this controller itself:

```
public function initialize()
        {

            $this->view->disable();

            $this->s3 = Aws::factory(CommonLibrary.'awsConfig.php')->get('s3')->registerStreamWrapper();
            $this->aws = Aws::factory(CommonLibrary.'awsConfig.php');
            $this->prefix='folder/';  //i dont why this prefix is for.
    $this->bucket="bucketname"; //my bucketname


            // Get the client from the builder by namespace
            $this->client = $this->aws->get('S3');
```

My issue is cant able to identify the exact problem how can I check the issue.?

Comment: Can you confirm the policies are the same on the old and new S3 bucket ?

Comment: I'm not sure about that what are the things present in policies , key,Secret key or anything else..?

Comment: @AbdulWaheed you can inspect the policy for each bucket in the S3 console.  They are one way of granting specific IAM users permission to access bucket.  IAM users can also have policies attached to them, in the IAM console.